# Is a large breadcrumb good enough for a page title?

Tags: navigation, layout, breadcrumbs, header

We have a breadcrumb under the menu and and the page title under the bread crumb. Can I get rid of the page title since it is really just a repeat of the breadcrumb? BTW, this is a LOB application internal to the company.

Example below, left vs. right:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKmU8n.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: From an HTML markup perspective they're likely two different things. A breadcrumb is a menu (or a list) and the other is a header/title.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest combining the two, missing the last part of the breadcrumb and wrapping the header down to the next line and maybe using a different symbol to denote a downward direction:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTQMYm.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: This is what I typically go with as well (when there's a need for breadcrumbs...but that's a different debate). I'd suggest that there's no need to go with a down arrow, however. In addition, be sure that the page title is actually a header tag of some sort (typically h1 or h2)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you need the breadcrumbs? The structure is rather clear, the hierarchy is within the vertical elements. The breadcrumbs seems to just duplicate it in a horizontal plane.
[image]

Comment: i agree with Alexey Kolchenko, in your case you don t need breadcrumbs which are used for deeper hidden Level menu. If there were sub menu under invoicing menu breadcrumbs were very helpfull ans usefull. Will you have more level s? But please don t mixe breadcrumb whith title. each thing has got a place and for each place there is a thing . title has to have got a place which will be the Same on each page. It will help your users to get habits and find quickly were they are. If you mixe breadcrumbs with title, your title will move horizontaly between each page  ...

Answer (score 2):

Go with the Left version. It is an anti-pattern to use the breadcrumbs instead of a page name. 
Reference: ["Don't Make Me Think, by Steve Krug, Chapter 6 - Street signs and Breadcrumbs"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321344758)